# Do we really need to provide more compute resource if the query load is low?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: snippet from the snowflake documentation]

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-load-monitoring.html

I see it as "If the running query load is low, then you could resize the warehouse to provide more compute resources." if the query load is low why should we provide more compute resource?As per my understanding if the query load is low then it make sense in reducing the warehouse size so that we get some cost savings..I am not getting it right.Please help me providing more insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not ignore the first sentence in the document:

> When you notice that a query is running slowly, check whether an
>   overloaded warehouse is causing the query to compete for resources or
>   get queued.

So if your query is running slow and there is no load on your warehouse, that means your query already uses available compute resources of the warehouse. In this case, you may consider resizing the warehouse to provide more compute resources. Of course, not all the queries get benefit from a bigger warehouse but you may give it a try.

Comment: Here the term 'there is no load " refers to  bar chart that shows as  "running"   (or)bar chart that shows as "queued" in "Warehouse Load Over Time graph"? .Incase case of no load does the graph "Warehouse Load Over Time graph" shows us nothing ?

Comment: Let me clarify my words: When I said "there is no load", I meant there is no significant load. For resource distribution for your concurrent queries, number of running queries are important. But you can not ignore the queue, because it indicates that the warehouse is overloaded all the time.